# I have a problem in the sass from the &_subtitle and &_plus - is the problem with the sass or the html?

Tags: html, css, sass

I have a problem in the sass from the &_subtitle and &_plus - is the problem with the sass or the html document?  Because the stylization of the text are on top of the images :/

```
.mobile
        min-height: 864px
        padding: 48px 0 79px 0
        background: url('../img/bg/mobile_app.png') center (center / cover) no-repeat
        .row
                margin-top: 32px
                &_item
                        width: 320px
                        height: 280px
                        margin: 0 auto
                        margin-bottom: 19px
                        padding-top: 92px
                &_1
                        background: url('../img/bg/mobile_screen_1.jpg') center (center / cover) no-repeat
                &_2
                        background: url('../img/bg/mobile_screen_2.jpg') center (center / cover) no-repeat
                &_3
                        background: url('../img/bg/mobile_screen_3.jpg') center (center / cover) no-repeat
                &_4
                        background: url('../img/bg/mobile_screen_4.jpg') center (center / cover) no-repeat
                &_5
                        background: url('../img/bg/mobile_screen_5.jpg') center (center / cover) no-repeat
                &_6
                        background: url('../img/bg/mobile_screen_6.jpg') center (center / cover) no-repeat
                &_subtitle
                        color: #ffffff
                        font-size: 24px
                        font-weight: 400
                        line-height: 31px
                        text-transform: uppercase
                        text-align: center
                &_plus
                        isplay: flex 
                        justify-content: center
                        align-items: center
                        position: absolute
                        bottom: 35px
                        left: 50%
                        transform: translateX(-50%)
                        width: 26px
                        height: 26px
                        background-color: #000000
                        margin: 0 auto
                        border-radius: 100%
                        cursor: pointer
```

Answer (score 1):

in a quick glance, I noticed the &_plus block has a typo.  From your description, this seems to be the problem.  **display: flex**

```
&_plus
      isplay: flex
```